# Paired Bluetooth device does not connect, 14.04 Desktop

Tags: wine, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth GPS device which has successfully paired, shows in the list of bluetooth devices.

However, I seem unable to connect to it to allow my satnav software to use it (PC Navigator 14 free via wine).

Have I missed something here?

OK, I found a useful link [here](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure) and, using blueman software have definitely connected bluetooth to the GPS device and created a symbolic link to com1.  BUT...  the software doesn't seem to recognise the com port!

ANybody else seen this?

Comment: You might want to look at http://wiki.winehq.org/USB

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now confused!  Does Ubuntu see the Bluetooth device as a USB device?  Does wine see the Bluetooth device as a USB device?

Comment: Most of the bluetooth devices will be listed when you use command `lsusb` in terminal.  I don't know if wine has a way to use them or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've discovered why wine couldn't see the bluetooth ports:

1. Used blueman bluetooth manager to connect to the device and set up a serial port /dev/rfcomm0
2. Create a link to the serial port in ~/.wine/dosdevices:

   ```
    ln -s /dev/rfcomm0 com1
   ```
3. Add myself to dialout group so I can access the ports created in /dev:

   ```
    sudo gpasswd -a steve dialout
   ```

wine apps can now see serial ports.

I still have a problem with the app not keeping hold of the com port but that's another question!